# Multiple partners in a family tree in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, charts, family-tree

I [have a family tree](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljm3x50d/) from [Cyril's amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31367673/145190) but I'm trying to figure out how to adjust it to support multiple partners. In this case, I added a "Mistress" node and am trying to denote that "Mistress" and "John" had a child named "Hidden Son".

The current data structure works like this:

[image]

In that, the `root` object stores everything. It has a `children` array which contains the up most "generation" with no parents. It also contains an object that contains the children of these sibling objects/nodes. In the example above, this is `root.children[2]`.

I'm thinking I would have to refactor the data structure's `children` and inject information about whos parents the child is from. Just having trouble conceptualizing this, as well as the line

The end would would be something like this, except mistress would be on the left side:

[image]

Comment: Hi @meder just wanted to let you know that i didn't receive the bounty you had set on this question...seems like its gone to the community  :(

Comment: @Cyril - how? I chose your answer??

Comment: Yeah i am asking the same question to SO support http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312522/i-didnt-get-the-bounty-for-a-question-i-answered/312544?noredirect=1#comment283829_312544
he says _Your answer is therefore ineligible for automatic awarding of the bounty and can only win the bounty if bounty owner take the explicit action of awarding it to you._

Comment: [Related meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312522/419956).

Comment: I think you need to unaccept and then accept the answer...I believe thats how it works

Comment: Ok did that. Also made a newer bounty as well.

Comment: so need to wait for next 7 days..to find another SO bug LOL

Comment: @meder http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312522/i-didnt-get-the-bounty-for-a-question-i-answered?cb=1

Comment: By the way, the way you award a bounty (you have to wait at least two days) is to click the box under the checkmark on the answer you've selected. Autoawarding only works if the answer was posted _during_ the bounty. Otherwise you must manually award by clicking the box under the checkmark. (Let me know when you've read this and I will be happy to clean up this comment.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@medder thanks for the appreciation!

To do that I have added a hidden node **between john and mistress**.

And added a child to that hidden node, so it appears as if john and mistress have a child "Hidden Son" 
So the JSON looks like

```
{
    name: "Mistress",
    id: 9000,
    no_parent: true
  }, {
    name: "",//this is the new node between Mistress and John
    id: 100,
    no_parent: true,//it has no parents
    hidden: true,
    children: [{
      // so this hidden node will have a child 
      // which will make it appear as if john and mistress has a child.
      name: "Hidden Son",
      id: 9001
    }]
  }, {
    name: "John",
    id: 16,
    no_parent: true
  },
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/fcd5q8fv/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. So it's necessary to have this hidden "child" object in between the parent objects in the list? I'm still trying to grasp your code.

Comment: By the way, how would you center the text if they overflow the box?

Comment: Yep! need to put in a hidden node in between just to give the visualization impression that the children belongs to john and mistress

Comment: Line no 19 -21 in http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/fcd5q8fv/1/ decides the x position for text... i have written some biz logic to center it. you are free to change it as per requirement http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/fcd5q8fv/1/

Comment: amazing. appreciate it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fcd5q8fv/7/ I'm trying to make a more scaled version of this. Would you know how to make the line from grandparents of John more center to him? or Ex Wife 3 right on top of Hidden Son 3? Or if you have any hints/ideas in general about how to scale this that I can try, or recommend another technology that'd be great.

Comment: Also if "Grandma" doesnt exist but there's just Grandpa, still be centered?

Comment: I can see that all the children are connected to grandma...you didn't create a hidden node between them..well the layout is given by tree layout so i am doing tricks like adding empty node to center it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97033/discussion-between-meder-and-cyril).

Comment: Does this support for adding parent dynamically?

Comment: @ZaheerKhorajiya in that case you need to clear + redraw the tree again...

Comment: Can you pls show me that how to add parents dynamically?