# Tree with children towards multiple side in d3.js (similar to family tree)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

```js
var treeData = [{
    "name": "Device",
    "parent": "null"
  }

];
var treeData2 = [{
    "name": "Device",
    "parent": "null"
  }

];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 1260 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
      return [d.y, d.x];
    });

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


  makeRightTree();
  makeLeftTree();
});


function makeRightTree() {
  // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 1260 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
      return [d.y, d.x];
    });

  var svg = d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(600,0)");

  root = treeData[0];
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  update(root);



  function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        if (d.parent == "null") {
          return "node rightparent" //since its root its parent is null
        } else
          return "node rightchild" //all nodes with parent will have this class
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "-10")
      .attr("y", "-15")
      .attr("height", 30)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("rx", 15)
      .attr("ry", 15)
      .style("fill", "#f1f1f1");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    var addRightChild = nodeEnter.append("g");
    addRightChild.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "90")
      .attr("y", "-10")
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("rx", 10)
      .attr("ry", 10)
      .style("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2")
      .style("fill", "#ccc");

    addRightChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 95)
      .attr("y1", 1)
      .attr("x2", 105)
      .attr("y2", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");

    addRightChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 100)
      .attr("y1", -4)
      .attr("x2", 100)
      .attr("y2", 6)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");


    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
      });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      }).on("click", removelink);

    function removelink(d) {
      //this is the links target node which you want to remove
      var target = d.target;
      //make new set of children
      var children = [];
      //iterate through the children 
      target.parent.children.forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.id != target.id) {
          //add to teh child list if target id is not same 
          //so that the node target is removed.
          children.push(child);
        }
      });
      //set the target parent with new set of children sans the one which is removed
      target.parent.children = children;
      //redraw the parent since one of its children is removed
      update(d.target.parent)
    }

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x,
          y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      })
      .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });


    addRightChild.on("click", function(d) {

      event.stopPropagation();
      $("#child-info").show();
      $("#child-text").val("");

      $("#btn-add-child").off('click');
      $("#btn-add-child").click(function() {
        var childname = $("#child-text").val();

        if (typeof d.children === 'undefined') {


          var newChild = [{
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          }];

          console.log(tree.nodes(newChild[0]));
          var newnodes = tree.nodes(newChild);
          d.children = newnodes[0];
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);


        } else {
          var newChild = {
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          };
          console.log(d.children);
          d.children.push(newChild);
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);


        }



        $("#child-info").hide();
      });




    });;


  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

    // console.log(d);
    // if (d.children) {
    //  d._children = d.children;
    //  d.children = null;
    // } else {
    //  d.children = d._children;
    //  d._children = null;
    // }
    // update(d);
  }



}


function makeLeftTree() {
  // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 1260 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
      return [d.y, d.x];
    });

  var svg = d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-421,0)");

  root = treeData2[0];
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = width;

  update(root);



  function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.y = width - (d.depth * 180);
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        if (d.parent == "null") {
          return "node leftparent" //since its root its parent is null
        } else
          return "node leftchild" //all nodes with parent will have this class
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "-10")
      .attr("y", "-15")
      .attr("height", 30)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("rx", 15)
      .attr("ry", 15)
      .style("fill", "#f1f1f1");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    var addLeftChild = nodeEnter.append("g");
    addLeftChild.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "-30")
      .attr("y", "-10")
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("rx", 10)
      .attr("ry", 10)
      .style("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2")
      .style("fill", "#ccc");

    addLeftChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", -25)
      .attr("y1", 1)
      .attr("x2", -15)
      .attr("y2", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");

    addLeftChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", -20)
      .attr("y1", -4)
      .attr("x2", -20)
      .attr("y2", 6)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");




    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
      });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      }).on("click", removelink);

    function removelink(d) {
      //this is the links target node which you want to remove
      var target = d.target;
      //make new set of children
      var children = [];
      //iterate through the children 
      target.parent.children.forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.id != target.id) {
          //add to teh child list if target id is not same 
          //so that the node target is removed.
          children.push(child);
        }
      });
      //set the target parent with new set of children sans the one which is removed
      target.parent.children = children;
      //redraw the parent since one of its children is removed
      update(d.target.parent)
    }

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x,
          y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      })
      .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {


      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });


    addLeftChild.on("click", function(d) {

      event.stopPropagation();
      $("#child-info").show();
      $("#child-text").val("");

      $("#btn-add-child").off('click');
      $("#btn-add-child").click(function() {
        var childname = $("#child-text").val();

        if (typeof d.children === 'undefined') {


          var newChild = [{
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          }];

          console.log(tree.nodes(newChild[0]));
          var newnodes = tree.nodes(newChild);
          d.children = newnodes[0];
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);
        } else {
          var newChild = {
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          };
          console.log(d.children);
          d.children.push(newChild);
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);


        }

        $("#child-info").hide();
      });

    });;


  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

    // console.log(d);
    // if (d.children) {
    //  d._children = d.children;
    //  d.children = null;
    // } else {
    //  d.children = d._children;
    //  d._children = null;
    // }
    // update(d);
  }
}
```

```css
#child-info {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  left: 40%;
}
#btn-add-child {} .control-bar {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px -2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
  color: #666;
}
.asset-title {
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}
.control-buttons {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
.control-buttons button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #85e0e0;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.rightparent>rect {
  display: none;
}
.leftparent>rect {
  fill: #f1f1f1;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="child-info" style="display:none">

  <input type="text" id="child-text" placeholder="child name">

  <button id="btn-add-child">add</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to learn `d3.js` for the purpose of making a structure that looks like this. Where i can add and remove nodes dynamically , and i have been partially successful. ( with the help of lots of geeks here in stack overflow).

code snippet is as follows. The following has been achieved with two trees placed back to back. One tree - right oriented and other left oriented. The root node of both the trees are superposed.

[image]

The current working is as follows.

Click plus on the respective side to add a node , click on the link to remove the node and it's children. If you check the working sample code snippet it may work well initially.

But since the two trees are separate entity , once both sides becomes highly asymmetric the position of two root nodes will be different and two nodes are visible. ( one of them will be hidden but you can see the links starting from a different point - to see this issue try adding a few nodes on one side until it's root node position changes ). Something like this.

[image]

**Now my question**

Am I going the wrong way here ? Is there a way to directly convert a single `json` file into such a structure. I researched a lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245751/how-do-you-create-a-family-tree-in-d3-js)
wonderful answer on making family tree by [Cyril](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3382204/cyril). But I guess this case is different. Is there a way to make this structure directly ?

Or is there a way to move the nodes together based on movement of one node ?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you will need to fix the root node.

This is how to fix the left/right roots.

Inside the function `makeLeftTree`.

```
  oldlx = root.x0 = height / 2; //store the center x position
  oldly = root.y0 = width; //store the center y position
```

Inside the function `makeRightTree`.

```
  oldrx = root.x0 = height / 2; //store the center x position
  oldry = root.y0 = width; //store the center y position
```

Then in the left node update you update the node position with the stored position.

```
 var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.parent =="null"){
          d.y = oldly;
          d.x = oldlx;
        }
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });
```

Same in the right node update you update the node position with the stored position.

```
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.parent =="null"){
          d.y = oldry;
          d.x = oldrx;
        }

        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2Jcqh12cxVyToLdXun6?p=preview)

Comment: Can we create also create a Tree with Left/Right nodes for each Node (instead of just Root node) ?

Comment: @Cyril can you look at this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091411/level-3-nodes-are-far-away-from-level-2-node