# Make a dynamic tree with d3 V7

Tags: d3.js, tree

I want to make a tree with d3 v7, which allows me to add nodes on each side. I found a code on Stack Overflow ([Tree with children towards multiple side in d3.js (similar to family tree)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684608/tree-with-children-towards-multiple-side-in-d3-js-similar-to-family-tree)) that uses V3 but I'd like to adapt it to V7 (something I can't do properly because I don't know enough about this library and I have trouble understanding all the docs)

So I tried to modify the code to work with V7 like the d3.layout.tree() etc but nothing does it I must be doing it wrong. Does anyone know where the code goes wrong? If it is possible or if I have to start from the beginning?

Here is mine

```
import { hierarchy, tree } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-hierarchy@3.1.2"
var treeData = [{
    "name": "Device",
    "parent": "null"
  }

];
var treeData2 = [{
    "name": "Device",
    "parent": "null"
  }

];

$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("=====> READY");
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 1260 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var treeLayout = d3.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(d => d.y)
      .y(d => d.x);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


  makeRightTree();
  makeLeftTree();
});


function makeRightTree() {
  // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 1260 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var treeLayout = d3.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(d => d.y)
      .y(d => d.x);

  var svg = d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(600,0)");

  root = treeData[0];
  var oldrx = root.x0 = height / 2;
  var oldry = root.y0 = 0;

  update(root);



  function update(source) {

    // create a hierarchy from the root
    const treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root)
    tree(treeRoot)
    // nodes
    const nodes = treeRoot.descendants()
    // links
    const links = treeRoot.links()

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        if (d.parent == "null") {
          return "node rightparent" //since its root its parent is null
        } else
          return "node rightchild" //all nodes with parent will have this class
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "-10")
      .attr("y", "-15")
      .attr("height", 30)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("rx", 15)
      .attr("ry", 15)
      .style("fill", "#f1f1f1");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    var addRightChild = nodeEnter.append("g");
    addRightChild.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "90")
      .attr("y", "-10")
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("rx", 10)
      .attr("ry", 10)
      .style("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2")
      .style("fill", "#ccc");

    addRightChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 95)
      .attr("y1", 1)
      .attr("x2", 105)
      .attr("y2", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");

    addRightChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 100)
      .attr("y1", -4)
      .attr("x2", 100)
      .attr("y2", 6)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");


    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.parent =="null"){
          d.y = oldry;
          d.x = oldrx;
        }
        
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
      });
      

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      }).on("click", removelink);

    function removelink(d) {
      //this is the links target node which you want to remove
      var target = d.target;
      //make new set of children
      var children = [];
      //iterate through the children 
      target.parent.children.forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.id != target.id) {
          //add to teh child list if target id is not same 
          //so that the node target is removed.
          children.push(child);
        }
      });
      //set the target parent with new set of children sans the one which is removed
      target.parent.children = children;
      //redraw the parent since one of its children is removed
      update(d.target.parent)
    }

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x,
          y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      })
      .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });


    addRightChild.on("click", function(d) {

      event.stopPropagation();
      $("#child-info").show();
      $("#child-text").val("");

      $("#btn-add-child").off('click');
      $("#btn-add-child").click(function() {
        var childname = $("#child-text").val();

        if (typeof d.children === 'undefined') {


          var newChild = [{
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          }];

          console.log(tree(newChild[0]));
          var newnodes = d3.hierarchy(newChild[0], d => d.children);
          d.children = newnodes;
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);
          



        } else {
          var newChild = {
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          };
          console.log(d.children);
          d.children.push(newChild);
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);


        }



        $("#child-info").hide();
      });




    });;


  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

    // console.log(d);
    // if (d.children) {
    //  d._children = d.children;
    //  d.children = null;
    // } else {
    //  d.children = d._children;
    //  d._children = null;
    // }
    // update(d);
  }



}


function makeLeftTree() {
  // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 1260 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var treeLayout = d3.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(d => d.y)
      .y(d => d.x);

  var svg = d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-421,0)");

  root = treeData2[0];
  var oldlx = root.x0 = height / 2;
  var oldly = root.y0 = width;

  update(root);



  function update(source) {

    
    // create a hierarchy from the root
    const treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root)
    tree(treeRoot)
    // nodes
    const nodes = treeRoot.descendants()
    // links
    const links = treeRoot.links()

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.y = width - (d.depth * 180);
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        if (d.parent == "null") {
          return "node leftparent" //since its root its parent is null
        } else
          return "node leftchild" //all nodes with parent will have this class
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "-10")
      .attr("y", "-15")
      .attr("height", 30)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("rx", 15)
      .attr("ry", 15)
      .style("fill", "#f1f1f1");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    var addLeftChild = nodeEnter.append("g");
    addLeftChild.append("rect")
      .attr("x", "-30")
      .attr("y", "-10")
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("rx", 10)
      .attr("ry", 10)
      .style("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2")
      .style("fill", "#ccc");

    addLeftChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", -25)
      .attr("y1", 1)
      .attr("x2", -15)
      .attr("y2", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");

    addLeftChild.append("line")
      .attr("x1", -20)
      .attr("y1", -4)
      .attr("x2", -20)
      .attr("y2", 6)
      .attr("stroke", "#444")
      .style("stroke-width", "2");




    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (d.parent =="null"){
          d.y = oldly;
          d.x = oldlx;
        }
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
      });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      }).on("click", removelink);

    function removelink(d) {
      //this is the links target node which you want to remove
      var target = d.target;
      //make new set of children
      var children = [];
      //iterate through the children 
      target.parent.children.forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.id != target.id) {
          //add to teh child list if target id is not same 
          //so that the node target is removed.
          children.push(child);
        }
      });
      //set the target parent with new set of children sans the one which is removed
      target.parent.children = children;
      //redraw the parent since one of its children is removed
      update(d.target.parent)
    }

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x,
          y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      })
      .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {


      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });


    addLeftChild.on("click", function(d) {

      event.stopPropagation();
      $("#child-info").show();
      $("#child-text").val("");

      $("#btn-add-child").off('click');
      $("#btn-add-child").click(function() {
        var childname = $("#child-text").val();

        if (typeof d.children === 'undefined') {


          var newChild = [{
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          }];

          console.log(tree(newChild[0]));
          var newnodes = d3.hierarchy(newChild[0], d => d.children);
          d.children = newnodes;
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);


        } else {
          var newChild = {
            "name": childname,
            "parent": "Son Of A",
          };
          console.log(d.children);
          d.children.push(newChild);
          console.log(d.children);
          update(d);


        }

        $("#child-info").hide();
      });

    });;


  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

    // console.log(d);
    // if (d.children) {
    //  d._children = d.children;
    //  d.children = null;
    // } else {
    //  d.children = d._children;
    //  d._children = null;
    // }
    // update(d);
  }
}
```

```
#child-info {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  left: 40%;
}
#btn-add-child {} .control-bar {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px -2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
  color: #666;
}
.asset-title {
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}
.control-buttons {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
.control-buttons button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #85e0e0;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.rightparent>rect {
  display: none;
}
.leftparent>rect {
  fill: #f1f1f1;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```
<div id="child-info" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" id="child-text" placeholder="child name">
  <button id="btn-add-child">add</button>  
</div>
```