# Adding siblings to nodes in a family tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094) shows d3 being used to draw an ancestry chart.

I have been looking at chart having the ancestors, descendants and siblings as shown below. In the example John Doe, Mary Joe and Jacob Joes are siblings.

This is tree for John Doe. The tree for B1 Doe is collapsed. It will be complex if her tree is also shown in this chart. If that is done, her ancestor edges/links will cross with John Doe's.

Can a tree like this can be drawn with d3?

[image]

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245751/how-do-you-create-a-family-tree-in-d3-js

Comment: can you share code please ? thank you